# Split a matrix into a bunch of matrices on the basis of a column

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have the matrix which has the following structure:-

```
dput(wxc)
structure(c(238.946801420338, 223.142535708038, 274.619261046371, 
273.439733090487, 215.706452885888, 119.775408012924, 309.133892578419, 
179.427886746935, 184.964414147966, 147.869054809391, 350.414967881055, 
224.977605880985, 251.492881355031, 262.693771803449, 257.408117669569, 
201.126389452869, 114.11659518868, 289.932912590756, 163.496138752858, 
175.273982760559, 147.328923667829, 196.271621915704, 155.29449412769, 
167.93000111555, 219.804699259836, 237.09122598576, 209.875403776858, 
256.360078818592, 216.766568194638, 289.555003771118, 206.88715153863, 
178.599223124703, 3850.51983512865, 3913.15097378778, 6073.89788008637, 
6225.91284714043, 5288.5450129915, 2743.5615574449, 6306.08530302386, 
3454.30549116055, 3346.78377861025, 2832.88121325859, 5687.01868900979, 
3443.56944040405, 2925.96876616993, 5387.24442872102, 5326.94995783789, 
4147.62253972426, 2802.8392067073, 5095.63008832554, 2811.3723495583, 
2914.25682383665, 2693.48336048641, 5033.13664894361, 3154.1547817313, 
3441.32976346843, 4357.78322304993, 5669.73097863166, 4384.91633906459, 
4690.40166056736, 4680.11580177635, 4067.61475423759, 4049.15540187979, 
3976.68838063037, 5.33575956744028, 5.79602619241276, 8.17668059019808, 
7.61069756648117, 5.98055862294587, 6.19871994250888, 6.23239390929145, 
7.07660225732825, 6.64842077412756, 5.92122044101024, 6.98968965866075, 
5.64117422534395, 5.05993061428474, 7.33061422949852, 7.06427314520514, 
5.22745924829043, 5.0123708006706, 6.03004989617556, 5.94923597164888, 
6.30647034986393, 4.89882513313254, 5.77514577537824, 5.31467015208418, 
7.29510776744718, 6.60634063766906, 8.63230903116024, 11.1499643389025, 
5.86504619519451, 7.11327716853739, 6.17447784501154, 6.38940771325398, 
8.09971039715566, 17.0877083827147, 20.3822702574889, 22.9781636736483, 
22.7666286458737, 24.2118772208673, 23.3792760350328, 20.44644966464, 
20.2948742993018, 19.9574319559545, 20.099738930559, 16.5692963857771, 
16.9301297132199, 16.3922812035515, 20.34712809589, 21.0756746538823, 
20.2788000745702, 25.3658755828692, 18.2369494976225, 17.0032518971888, 
18.4897845273291, 20.7516226235008, 25.0389933200027, 22.2446603969889, 
21.5450397403876, 21.5604691510509, 24.0900763096915, 21.5545428060378, 
18.5495182337993, 22.7369282824886, 21.4217522050381, 20.4252739020404, 
22.9938101229643, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), dim = c(32L, 
5L))
```

And it looks like following:-

```
wxc
#           [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4] [,5]
#  [1,] 238.9468 3850.520  5.335760 17.08771    1
#  [2,] 223.1425 3913.151  5.796026 20.38227    1
#  [3,] 274.6193 6073.898  8.176681 22.97816    1
#  [4,] 273.4397 6225.913  7.610698 22.76663    1
#  [5,] 215.7065 5288.545  5.980559 24.21188    1
#  [6,] 119.7754 2743.562  6.198720 23.37928    1
#  [7,] 309.1339 6306.085  6.232394 20.44645    1
#  [8,] 179.4279 3454.305  7.076602 20.29487    1
#  [9,] 184.9644 3346.784  6.648421 19.95743    1
# [10,] 147.8691 2832.881  5.921220 20.09974    1
# [11,] 350.4150 5687.019  6.989690 16.56930    1
# [12,] 224.9776 3443.569  5.641174 16.93013    2
# [13,] 251.4929 2925.969  5.059931 16.39228    2
# [14,] 262.6938 5387.244  7.330614 20.34713    2
# [15,] 257.4081 5326.950  7.064273 21.07567    2
# [16,] 201.1264 4147.623  5.227459 20.27880    2
# [17,] 114.1166 2802.839  5.012371 25.36588    2
# [18,] 289.9329 5095.630  6.030050 18.23695    2
# [19,] 163.4961 2811.372  5.949236 17.00325    2
# [20,] 175.2740 2914.257  6.306470 18.48978    2
# [21,] 147.3289 2693.483  4.898825 20.75162    2
# [22,] 196.2716 5033.137  5.775146 25.03899    3
# [23,] 155.2945 3154.155  5.314670 22.24466    3
# [24,] 167.9300 3441.330  7.295108 21.54504    3
# [25,] 219.8047 4357.783  6.606341 21.56047    3
# [26,] 237.0912 5669.731  8.632309 24.09008    3
# [27,] 209.8754 4384.916 11.149964 21.55454    3
# [28,] 256.3601 4690.402  5.865046 18.54952    3
# [29,] 216.7666 4680.116  7.113277 22.73693    3
# [30,] 289.5550 4067.615  6.174478 21.42175    3
# [31,] 206.8872 4049.155  6.389408 20.42527    3
# [32,] 178.5992 3976.688  8.099710 22.99381    3
```

I wanted to know if there was a way to split this matrix into a list of matrices on the basis of the 5th column.

The final list will have the following structure:-

```
list(structure(c(238.946801420338, 223.142535708038, 274.619261046371,
273.439733090487, 215.706452885888, 119.775408012924, 309.133892578419,
179.427886746935, 184.964414147966, 147.869054809391, 350.414967881055,
3850.51983512865, 3913.15097378778, 6073.89788008637, 6225.91284714043,
5288.5450129915, 2743.5615574449, 6306.08530302386, 3454.30549116055,
3346.78377861025, 2832.88121325859, 5687.01868900979, 5.33575956744028,
5.79602619241276, 8.17668059019808, 7.61069756648117, 5.98055862294587,
6.19871994250888, 6.23239390929145, 7.07660225732825, 6.64842077412756,
5.92122044101024, 6.98968965866075, 17.0877083827147, 20.3822702574889,
22.9781636736483, 22.7666286458737, 24.2118772208673, 23.3792760350328,
20.44644966464, 20.2948742993018, 19.9574319559545, 20.099738930559,
16.5692963857771, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), dim = c(11L,
5L)), structure(c(224.977605880985, 251.492881355031, 262.693771803449,
257.408117669569, 201.126389452869, 114.11659518868, 289.932912590756,
163.496138752858, 175.273982760559, 147.328923667829, 3443.56944040405,
2925.96876616993, 5387.24442872102, 5326.94995783789, 4147.62253972426,
2802.8392067073, 5095.63008832554, 2811.3723495583, 2914.25682383665,
2693.48336048641, 5.64117422534395, 5.05993061428474, 7.33061422949852,
7.06427314520514, 5.22745924829043, 5.0123708006706, 6.03004989617556,
5.94923597164888, 6.30647034986393, 4.89882513313254, 16.9301297132199,
16.3922812035515, 20.34712809589, 21.0756746538823, 20.2788000745702,
25.3658755828692, 18.2369494976225, 17.0032518971888, 18.4897845273291,
20.7516226235008, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), dim = c(10L,
5L)), structure(c(196.271621915704, 155.29449412769, 167.93000111555,
219.804699259836, 237.09122598576, 209.875403776858, 256.360078818592,
216.766568194638, 289.555003771118, 206.88715153863, 178.599223124703,
5033.13664894361, 3154.1547817313, 3441.32976346843, 4357.78322304993,
5669.73097863166, 4384.91633906459, 4690.40166056736, 4680.11580177635,
4067.61475423759, 4049.15540187979, 3976.68838063037, 5.77514577537824,
5.31467015208418, 7.29510776744718, 6.60634063766906, 8.63230903116024,
11.1499643389025, 5.86504619519451, 7.11327716853739, 6.17447784501154,
6.38940771325398, 8.09971039715566, 25.0389933200027, 22.2446603969889,
21.5450397403876, 21.5604691510509, 24.0900763096915, 21.5545428060378,
18.5495182337993, 22.7369282824886, 21.4217522050381, 20.4252739020404,
22.9938101229643, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), dim = c(11L,
5L)))
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `split()` on your matrix. You can specify which group you would like to use for splitting, in your case that would be column 5:

```
mat |> split(mat[,5])
$`1`
 [1]  238.946801  223.142536  274.619261  273.439733  215.706453  119.775408  309.133893  179.427887  184.964414  147.869055  350.414968 3850.519835 3913.150974
[14] 6073.897880 6225.912847 5288.545013 2743.561557 6306.085303 3454.305491 3346.783779 2832.881213 5687.018689    5.335760    5.796026    8.176681    7.610698
[27]    5.980559    6.198720    6.232394    7.076602    6.648421    5.921220    6.989690   17.087708   20.382270   22.978164   22.766629   24.211877   23.379276
[40]   20.446450   20.294874   19.957432   20.099739   16.569296    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
[53]    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000

$`2`
 [1]  224.977606  251.492881  262.693772  257.408118  201.126389  114.116595  289.932913  163.496139  175.273983  147.328924 3443.569440 2925.968766 5387.244429
[14] 5326.949958 4147.622540 2802.839207 5095.630088 2811.372350 2914.256824 2693.483360    5.641174    5.059931    7.330614    7.064273    5.227459    5.012371
[27]    6.030050    5.949236    6.306470    4.898825   16.930130   16.392281   20.347128   21.075675   20.278800   25.365876   18.236949   17.003252   18.489785
[40]   20.751623    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000

$`3`
 [1]  196.271622  155.294494  167.930001  219.804699  237.091226  209.875404  256.360079  216.766568  289.555004  206.887152  178.599223 5033.136649 3154.154782
[14] 3441.329763 4357.783223 5669.730979 4384.916339 4690.401661 4680.115802 4067.614754 4049.155402 3976.688381    5.775146    5.314670    7.295108    6.606341
[27]    8.632309   11.149964    5.865046    7.113277    6.174478    6.389408    8.099710   25.038993   22.244660   21.545040   21.560469   24.090076   21.554543
[40]   18.549518   22.736928   21.421752   20.425274   22.993810    3.000000    3.000000    3.000000    3.000000    3.000000    3.000000    3.000000    3.000000
[53]    3.000000    3.000000    3.000000
```

To turn those vectors back into matrices you can use `lapply()`

```
mat |>
  split(mat[,5]) |>
  lapply(\(x) matrix(x,ncol = 5))
```

That returns a list of matrices:

```
$`1`
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 238.9468 3850.520 5.335760 17.08771    1
 [2,] 223.1425 3913.151 5.796026 20.38227    1
 [3,] 274.6193 6073.898 8.176681 22.97816    1
 [4,] 179.4279 6225.913 7.610698 22.76663    1
 [5,] 184.9644 5288.545 5.980559 24.21188    1
 [6,] 147.8691 2743.562 6.198720 23.37928    1
 [7,] 350.4150 6306.085 6.232394 20.44645    1
 [8,] 273.4397 3454.305 7.076602 20.29487    1
 [9,] 215.7065 3346.784 6.648421 19.95743    1
[10,] 119.7754 2832.881 5.921220 20.09974    1
[11,] 309.1339 5687.019 6.989690 16.56930    1

$`2`
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 224.9776 3443.569 5.641174 16.93013    2
 [2,] 251.4929 2925.969 5.059931 16.39228    2
 [3,] 262.6938 5387.244 7.330614 20.34713    2
 [4,] 257.4081 5326.950 7.064273 21.07567    2
 [5,] 201.1264 4147.623 5.227459 20.27880    2
 [6,] 114.1166 2802.839 5.012371 25.36588    2
 [7,] 289.9329 5095.630 6.030050 18.23695    2
 [8,] 163.4961 2811.372 5.949236 17.00325    2
 [9,] 175.2740 2914.257 6.306470 18.48978    2
[10,] 147.3289 2693.483 4.898825 20.75162    2

$`3`
          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 196.2716 5033.137  5.775146 25.03899    3
 [2,] 155.2945 3154.155  5.314670 22.24466    3
 [3,] 167.9300 3441.330  7.295108 21.54504    3
 [4,] 219.8047 4357.783  6.606341 21.56047    3
 [5,] 237.0912 5669.731  8.632309 24.09008    3
 [6,] 209.8754 4384.916 11.149964 21.55454    3
 [7,] 256.3601 4690.402  5.865046 18.54952    3
 [8,] 216.7666 4680.116  7.113277 22.73693    3
 [9,] 289.5550 4067.615  6.174478 21.42175    3
[10,] 206.8872 4049.155  6.389408 20.42527    3
[11,] 178.5992 3976.688  8.099710 22.99381    3
```

Comment: But this does not returns a list of matrices. Rather, it returns a list of vectors.

Comment: I have edited my answer to return matrices.